# How to focus user Input with fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

When the user clicks on a text input lower down on the screen and the keyboard overlay appears for input how do we move the fragment area into view so the user can visually see what they are typing, in an entry field.

I was able to elevate the problem somewhat in other areas with **android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"** for activities, but how do you go about this with fragments, on Android 11?

[image: Visual of the problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First solution:

For Fragments, you will need to add this.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

For Activities, you will ned to add this.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

second solution:

Add the layout inside of a scroll view.